# Mutt and mail attachments

Tags: mutt

How do you handle mail attachments when checking mails in Mutt?

I have set up [`auto_view`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#auto-view) for HTML files:

```
bind  attach  <return>  view-mailcap
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html text
unauto_view *
auto_view text/html
```

But if there are any images attached to the mail there is no way for me to know it, unless I go and check "view attachments".

Sometimes, the pager displays the following:

```
[-- Attachment #1: tutorial.pdf --]
[-- Type: application/pdf, Encoding: base64, Size: 320K --]
[-- application/pdf is unsupported (use 'v' to view this part) --]`
```

If `[-- Attachment #1: x --]` appeared every time it would be great, but it doesn't seem to work with inline pictures.

As a result, I have to remember to check it every time.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutt should show you attachments as long as they are part of a `multipart/alternative` MIME, no matter what the attachments are (it may say *unsupported* but the `Attachment #` line will be there).  Yet, some email clients build the MIME as follows (notably Apple Mail and iPhone mail):

```
  I     1 <no description>             [multipa/alternativ, 7bit, 496K]
  I     2 ├─><no description>         [text/plain, quoted, utf-8, 3.5K]
  I     3 └─><no description>             [multipa/related, 7bit, 492K]
  I     4   ├─><no description>         [text/html, quoted, utf-8, 17K]
  I     5   └─>Screen Shot.png                [image/png, base64, 474K]
```

Mutt cannot deal with this image because the image is inside another multipart MIME, a MIME which is not meant to contain attachments.  At least this is the scenario where my `mutt` does not display the attachments.

The reasoning behind it is that `multipart/related` is not meant to be used for attachments but [display suggestions, according to the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387)

Reference:

- [Original mutt-users list](http://mutt-users.mutt.narkive.com/7SFSVVeO/attachment-count-issue-with-multipart-messages)

Comment: If I add `alternative_order multipart/related text/html text/plain` to my config file, it displays the attachments from Mail.app but is it a bad idea ?

Comment: @joyeuxlutin - Not really, it should be fine.  There are people that have `text/enriched` as the first MIME in `alternative_order` and they survive.  It is just something that you need to keep in mind, if an email displays as a CSS file when you open it (that's super rare) then you know that you need to hit `v`.

Comment: Once upon a time you could display attachments with external applications based on the contents of `mailcap`.  You could have multiple entries for the same MIME type, so that you could f.i. decode PDF files inline with `pdftotext` (and include the text in replies), and still view the file in `acroread` when going through the attachment menu.  This worked fine for 15+ years. Then the current maintainers (I presume) decided they don't really understand what that part of the code was for, and removed that feature.  Tough luck.